# Is it possible to carry history of a file from a git branch to another (using command line)

Tags: git, logging

I've two branches in one repo : branch_1 and branch_2.

### Scenario 1

somebody added a file in branch_1 let's say **first_file.txt**. To get this file in branch_2 - I'll simply raise a pull request and once the PR is merged I'll have the file in branch_2.

### Scenario 2

somebody added a file in branch_1 let's say **first_file.txt**.
Now to get this file, I do below on terminal :

```
(on branch branch_1) $ git pull  

(on branch branch_1) $ git checkout branch_2

(on branch branch_2) $ git checkout branch_1 first_file.txt

and then performs git add,commit and push.
```

In both above scenarios I get the file in my branch (branch_2). but the issue is when I see git log (or history on git portal) they are completely different.

For Scenario 1 : it shows that file came from somebody.

For Scenario 2 : it shows that file is checked-in by me.

Is there a solution to copy files from one branch to another using command line, keeping history safe?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only history in a Git repository is the set of commits in the repository.

Each commit contains a complete snapshot of *every* file—or rather, of every file that is in that commit.  That is, suppose we start with a simple repository with one commit containing one file:

```
A   <-- master (HEAD)
```

(`A` stands in for some raw hash ID).  Commit `A` contains a `README.md` file, and nothing else.

Now you make a new commit in which you add a new file, such as `main.py`:

```
A--B   <-- master (HEAD)
```

New commit `B` contains *two* files: `README.md`—which is the same as the copy in commit `A`—and `main.py`.

The *history* in this repository is that commit `B` leads back to commit `A`.  That's the only history there is.

In your case, you have a more complex starting setup.  Simplified, it probably looks about like this:

```
          I--J   <-- branch_1
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K   <-- branch_2
```

Commit `H` is the first commit where the two branches join, in terms of history: history from `J` backwards goes `J`, `I`, `H`, `G`, and so on.  History from `K` goes `K`, `H`, `G`, and so on.

In commits up through `I`, and your commits up through `K`, there is no file named `first_file.txt`, but in commit `J`, someone else added this new file.  Therefore commit `J` has all the files that `I` has, plus this one new file.  Viewing the history from `J` backwards, the difference between `I` and `J` is that the file is added.

If you now make a new commit `L` that comes after `K` that has the file in it, the difference between commit `K` and your new commit `L` is that this file is added.  So the history as viewed from `L` backwards shows the file added.

That's simply how Git works.  There is no *file* history, there is only *commit* history.  You can ask Git to produce a subset of commit history that traces which commits had activity in specific files—but since the *commit* history will be that the file newly appears in `L` as compared to `K`, that is what you will see.